# Type C Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, study, berlin

I applied for a Schengen visa to attend a 20-day summer school program in Berlin and was issued one, valid for a little more than a month, which says "Geschäftsvisum erwerbstätigkeit nicht gestattet". It translates to *Business visa, employment not allowed*. What I am worried about is that I am a student and have an acceptance letter only for a summer school program. I do not have any documents to support a business visa. Do I have to get the sticker changed and if so what should it say in the remarks?

Sorry for the long question. My nationality is Indian.

Comment: C visa are issued for business and tourism, and a summer school is not exactly tourism. You should be fine as long as you get no money for what you do in Germany.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am also concerned because a friend of mine who applied for the same program, submitted similar documents as me, got student exchange/school visit. It simply doesn't make sense. Why do they enter such confusing phrases in the remarks field, rather than just leaving it blank if unsure.

Comment: @krish If you are concerned you should check with the embassy that issued your visa

Comment: Traveller is right. But note that a summer school participation does not quite perfectly fit the "student exchange / school visit" description either -- it is neither an exchange, not a visit to a (physical) school. It's more like participating in a non-degree course. Also, if you happen to be *employed* by your current institution, then the business category *may* actually fit better, because your summer school participation would be incidental to your employment (at home) then.

Comment: @Traveller I did contact the embassy and their response was even more confusing. When I called up they asked me to visit their office but at the office, one lady quickly dismissed it off as a non-issue and somehow I felt she didn't hear me out properly and brushed me off in a hurry because it was crowded. Anyway, I will be going there again this week. Any suggestions how to approach the people at the embassy to get a satisfactory reply?

Comment: @DCTLib Thank you so much. I agree that student exchange will not be right either. I guess both will have to visit the embassy together and get this straightened out.

Comment: @o.m. “Type C” visas (a somewhat obsolete terminology) are issued for everything and anything that requires a stay under 90 days. The form and suggested list of documents to submit with an application listed in annexes to the Schengen Visa code explicitly list several other purposes than just business and tourism.

Comment: @Relaxed, the OP was worried that he couldn't do a summer school on his visa. I thought he had no reason to worry.

Comment: @o.m. I share your feeling but I thought the first sentence could be confusing.

Comment: Thank you guys!!...Finished the program and am back to India. The visa was valid for my journey!